# spring cloud stream request-reply

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

in spring amqp i use rpc like this :

```
    public void send() {
    System.out.println(" [x] Requesting fib(" + start + ")");
    Integer response = (Integer) template.convertSendAndReceive
        (exchange.getName(), "rpc", start++);
    System.out.println(" [.] Got '" + response + "'");
}
```

but what can i do in spring cloud stream when i have multiple instance of sender and multiple instance of receiver ?
first , i need to know hot to get response in single instance mode
second , i need to know how to receive response in exact instance when have 
multiple instaces

Answer (score 1):

See this GH issue for some discussion and possible solution: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/815